# How to display label and select box in same line using Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-flex-layout

I have searched for keeping `input` and `label` in the same line using **Angular Material** but didn't got any answer around. Solutions are available only in html and css but here I am in the need of Angular material way.

And the try I have made to achieve it using `grid` and `flex layout` was like,

**Example:**   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btjbqw-6vykln

```
      <mat-grid-list cols="10" rowHeight="2:2">
        <mat-grid-tile colspan='2'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an sea similique maiestatis inciderint, decore recusabo sea in. Dolore putant laboramus duo in. Mundi doctus aliquid ut ius. At vero illum vocent vis. Ius eros argumentum cu. 
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile colspan='8' fxFlex>
        <mat-form-field  class="input-row" appearance="outline">
            <mat-select placeholder="Expenses" formControlName="expenses" required>
              <mat-option value="1">a</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="2">b</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="3">c</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="4">d</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>    
      </mat-grid-list>

      <mat-grid-list cols="10" rowHeight="2:2">
        <mat-grid-tile colspan='2'>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an sea similique maiestatis inciderint. 
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-grid-tile colspan='8' fxFlex>
        <mat-form-field  class="input-row" appearance="outline">
            <mat-select placeholder="Operating Adjustments" formControlName="operatingAdjustments" required>
              <mat-option value="1">e</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="2">f</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="3">g</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="4">h</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        </mat-grid-tile>    
      </mat-grid-list>
```

Here for every element I am repeating the `mat-grid-list` , `mat-grid-title`,`cols`, `rowHeight` for every element and I believe it is not the right way to achieve it.

In the `mat-grid-tile` I am having very lengthy text and I need to place that as label at left and the select box belong to that in the right.

Same way I am having more number of cases as some have big label text and some might have small text. So the select box needs to align centre with respective to it.

I want to display exactly like this image given below using Angular Material alone without any other library.

[image]

The reason for using `flexLayout` is also to make this entire form **responsive** which is also main important feature for this design.

May be I am entirely wrong with this approach, so any modification or different approach to the above code in example is also welcomed.

As in my example I have lots of code for this design(mainly repetition of same code), kindly help me to achieve the result with some optimised code which doesn't have any performance issue.

At the end expected result is same as the image above.

Answer (score 1):

This is the layout you want using flex!

`fxLayout.lt-sm="column"` for small devices convert row to col.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column"  fxLayoutAlign="flex-start center" class="full-width">
  <div fxFlex>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an sea similique maiestatis inciderint, decore recusabo sea in. Dolore putant laboramus duo in. Mundi doctus aliquid ut ius. At vero illum vocent vis. Ius eros argumentum cu.
  </div>
  <div fxFlex>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start center" class="full-width">
      <div fxFlex>
        <mat-form-field class="input-row" appearance="outline">
          <mat-select placeholder="Expenses" formControlName="expenses" required>
            <mat-option value="1">a</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="2">b</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="3">c</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="4">d</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start center" class="full-width">
      <div fxFlex>
        <mat-form-field class="input-row" appearance="outline">
          <mat-select placeholder="Expenses" formControlName="expenses" required>
            <mat-option value="1">a</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="2">b</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="3">c</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="4">d</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div fxFlex>
        Select
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

link for more details https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API

Comment: I have implemented your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-btjbqw-w7ouh5 and this is not as expected.. The select box is displayed below even in bigger screens.. I want result exactly like the image shown in the question..

Comment: Install `import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';`

Comment: You can download form here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout

Comment: No the label is below and the select box is displayed at top, I request you to produce stackblitz with your code,  the solution which you have given is not working as like the image shown above.. Label and select box should be in same line for bigger screens..

Comment: Sorry for that idk how to produce `stack-blitz` but you cans paste my code here and its working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material